# Scipy and CX_freeze - Error importing scipy: you cannot import scipy while being in scipy source directory

Tags: scipy, cx-freeze

I'm having trouble compiling an exe while using cx_freeze and scipy. In particular, my script uses

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
```

The build process seems to complete successfully, however when I try to run the compiled exe, I get the following message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "gis_helper.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 103, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Error importing scipy: you cannot import scipy while
        being in scipy source directory; please exit the scipy source
        tree first, and relaunch your python intepreter.
```

After looking at scipy\ _init__.py file, there is the following:

```
if __SCIPY_SETUP__:
    import sys as _sys
    _sys.stderr.write('Running from scipy source directory.\n')
    del _sys
else:
    try:
        from scipy.__config__ import show as show_config
    except ImportError:
        msg = """Error importing scipy: you cannot import scipy while
        being in scipy source directory; please exit the scipy source
        tree first, and relaunch your python intepreter."""
        raise ImportError(msg)
```

I'm not entirely sure what is the problem here however although it seems that the erros is being thrown because there is a problem with the scipy config file. Possibly not being included in the build process. I'm quite a novice and hoping someone more experienced with generating build using cxfreeze can shed some light on this.

Incidentally, the scipy in use was installed from binaries [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i have had the same issue. I added this code to the `setup.py` generated by cx_freeze:

```
import scipy
includefiles_list=[]
scipy_path = dirname(scipy.__file__)
includefiles_list.append(scipy_path)
```

Then, used `includefiles_list` as part of the build_exe parameter:

```
build_options = dict(packages=[], include_files=includefiles_list)

setup(name="foo", options=dict(build_exe=build_options))
```

Comment: Thanks that did work, unfortunately it's now moved onto other errors. Focussing on pyinstaller for the time being, but thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same issue. All tough when i test your code i get the following message `ImportError: No module named 'C:\\***\\***\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy`

Comment: The dirname() refers to os.path.dirname(), I suppose. How did you "add the includefiles to the buildExe parameter list"?

Comment: @np8, yes, dirname() refers to os.path.dirname(). I have updated my answer. Also check http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html

Answer (score 1):

I add the same problem and solved it using fepzzz method and including some missing packages:

```
additional_mods = ['numpy.matlib', 'multiprocessing.process']
includefiles = [(r'C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy')]

setup(xxx, options={'build_exe': {'includes': additional_mods, 'include_files': includefiles}})
```

And using version 5.0.2 of cx-Freeze package, which solved an error when importing multiprocessing.process